# Reasoning & use cases for JavaScript bind() function?

Tags: javascript

While exploring some new JavaScript stuff, I am wondering what is the reason behind the JavaScript `bind` function.

I understood what it does (passing a context for `this`), but I don't really get when to use it?

I tried to look through some of my projects and find parts where `bind` could have made things more elegant, but the only thing that came remotely close is this one (backbone.js code):

```
var AlbumListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var albums = new AlbumCollection();

        this.listenTo(albums, 'fetched-okay', function() { 
            console.log('fetch success, kick things off!');
        });

        albums.fetch({
            success: function() {
                this.trigger('fetched-okay');
            }.bind(albums),
        });
    },
});
```

Without `bind`, the call to `fetch` would look like this:

```
albums.fetch({
    success: function() {
        albums.trigger('fetched-okay');
    },
});
```

I think one could argue that the first example is maybe a bit easier to understand than the second example, although I not convinced by it ;-)

So what are some real use cases for the bind function – to me it seems like a real special niche-like function.

Comment: What do you think the value of `this` in the `success` function, without `bind`?

Comment: @thefourtheye Actually I thought it already is `albums`, but a simple `console.log(this)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Exactly. By default, `this` will be either `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object. So to explicitly bind the `albums` object, you are using `Function.prototype.bind`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you already have a variable like `albums` that you can use in the function, there is no reason to use `bind`.

However, `bind` is useful a) when you want to `bind(this)` b) when the function to be bound does use `this` and you cannot do anything about it.

So while

```
function() {
    this.trigger('fetched-okay');
}.bind(albums)
```

is hardly useful, it could be trivially replaced by

```
albums.trigger.bind(albums, 'fetched-okay');
```

where the `trigger` method itself is bound directly, and we don't use any function expression at all.